# Check overlap between objects, what is the "depsgraph" parameter?

Tags: scripting, bvh

Console says i need to put the "depsgraph" parameter when checking if 2 objects overlaps, what is that? since the API manual doesn't provide options what to put in.

[image]

```
import bpy
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.name.startswith("myobj_"):
        for obj2 in bpy.context.scene.objects:
            if obj2.name.startswith("target_"):
                isoverlap = BVHTree.FromObject(obj).overlap(BVHTree.FromObject(obj2))
                if isoverlap is not None:
                    print("overlapping")
```

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.evaluated_depsgraph_get

Comment: i tried `BVHTree.FromObject(obj, evaluated_depsgraph_get())` and `BVHTree.FromObject(obj, obj.evaluated_depsgraph_get())` both not working, how is the function looks like in action?